Почему text1.txt > text2.txt в cmd делает text2.txt пустым?
Если в первом файле был текст Hello, а во втором Hi, то при введении в командную строку команды text1.txt > text2.txt открывается файл text1.txt, и удаляется текст из файла text2.txt?
P.S. Я знаю, что для копирования текста в другой файл надо использовать type text1.txt > text2.txt, просто хочу разобраться, почему получается такой результат

Когда выполняется text1.txt > text2.txt это равносильно команде notepad.exe text1.txt > text2.txt файл text1.txt открывается блокнотом и в файл  text2.txt ничего не передается, вот это "ничего" и записывается в файл text2.txt.
